# How to generate a tiled map from a spherical mercator SVG?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, svg

I'm not a GIS person; this is really just a side task, so I probably have terminology/strategy incorrect; I would ask that you please bear with me. I have the following requirements for a Qt-based C++ application that I'm working on:

- Display a tiled map (e.g. OpenStreetMaps). I have this working well.
- Allow the overlay of other vector data on top of the map (as a test, I have a shapefile of world boundaries I got from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com).

Preprocessing of the vector data is possible in my application, so I decided to convert the EPSG:4326-projected Natural Earth shapefile to an SVG file (which I can render most easily in my application). I have done so using [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org). Its configuration looks like this:

```
{
   "layers": [{
       "src": "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp",
       "class": "world_boundaries"
   }],
   "proj": {
       "id": "proj4",
       "projstr": "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs "
   },
   "bounds": {
       "mode": "bbox",
       "data": [-180, -85.0511, 180, 85.0511]
   }
}
```

I believe this should take the input shapefile, reproject it to Spherical Mercator (which should match the projection of the OSM tiles), and generate a corresponding SVG. This all "works," but the projection of the SVG file seems to be a bit off, it seems. When I overlay the SVG features atop the OSM image tiles, they don't quite line up, like this:

[image]

The black one-pixel-wide lines are rendered from the SVG. I'm wondering if there's something conceptually that I'm doing wrong in the preprocessing steps. I *think* that I'm rendering the SVG tiles correctly (I'm treating the SVG document as a square image that is 360 degrees wide and 170.1022 degrees tall and just slicing out the square portion of that image that corresponds to each tile that I need). However, since GIS isn't my job, I'm sure my ignorance could be leading me astray somewhere.

Comment: What is the input spatial reference of the input shapefile? It looks like a datum conflict.. how did you reproject? what utility and what parameters? Are you rendering with the same origin? Seeing as you're this close then done something right.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: The input shape file's projection is `GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
` according to its `.prj` file. I used Kartograph.py as I described above, using the config file that I gave in the OP. I believe I'm using the same origin (which I assume is -180 degrees longitude and 85.0511 degrees latitude).

Comment: Have you viewed the data in a GIS program like QGIS (free to download & use) to see if it's the data or your applications' rendering that causes the disparity? I'm not familiar with Kartography.py, I would use GDAL_Warp (which comes with QGIS).

Comment: I will take a look at that. I wasn't aware that GDAL could write SVG files; that's why I had chosen the tool I'm using now.

Comment: Not so much SVG, I would use it for projection from WGS84/Geographic to a custom spatial reference as shapefiles then convert to SVG without transformation.

Comment: Easiest would be to use ogr2ogr (gdal is for rasters) to reproject natural earth to epsg:3857 and then SVG it. I think you issue is you told the conversion tool your data was already in spherical mercator, but I've never used it so that may be right.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to try some alternative tools to see if I had a problem in my workflow. At the suggestion of one of the commenters above, I instead did the following:

- I used `ogr2ogr` to reproject the input shapefile into EPSG:3857.
- I then used [shp2svg](https://github.com/kbh3rd/shptosvg) to convert the Spherical Mercator shapefile to an SVG.

This resulted in an SVG file that rendered properly in my application. I'm assuming there must be either a bug in Kartograph, or I may have been driving it incorrectly. I think I was using it correctly, but its documentation isn't as detailed as it could be.